# Mixed Integer Programming - variable that equals the sign of an expression

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I want to define the following:

`y = 1 if x<=th`

`= 0 otherwise`

Currently I'm doing the following:

Let's say we know the lower and upper bound of x-th. i.e. `L <= x-th <= U`

Then I am adding the following two constraints:

`x-th >= L*y`

`x-th <= U*(1-y)`

This works mostly, but when `x-th=0`, y could be both `1` or `0`. How do I handle this scenario when `x-th=0`. I want y to be `1` not `0`.

Comment: Are you minimizing or maximizing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small constant tolerance and impose
$$Ly + \epsilon(1-y) \le x - \text{th} \le 0y + U(1-y)$$
Then $y = 1 \implies L \le x-\text{th} \le 0$, and $y = 0 \implies \epsilon \le x - \text{th} \le U$.

Comment: Hi @RobPratt, this is unrelated to your answer, hence I would be deleting this comment soonest. Please could you help out with this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4441875/585488